# SSL configuration is not working in Wildfly 26.0.1

Tags: ssl, configuration, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-26

We are trying to migrate Wildfly from **8.1.0.Final** to **26.0.1.Final**. Currently Wildfly is running in standalone mode hence standalone.xml is in used for configurations and no domain configuration so far.

Everything is working that includes, management console, package deployments etc but requesting URL with https gives us "**This site can't be reached**". It appears there is something wrong with SSL configuration in Wildfly 26.0.1.Final because same SSL certificate have been used in version 8.1.0.Final.

Here is SSL/TLS configuration we are using:

```
            <tls>
                <key-stores>
                    <key-store name="abc-keystore">
                        <credential-reference clear-text="clearpasswordonetwothree"/>
                        <implementation type="JKS"/>
                        <file path="abc-keystore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                    </key-store>
                </key-stores>
                <key-managers>
                    <key-manager name="applicationKM" key-store="abc-keystore">
                        <credential-reference clear-text="clearpasswordonetwothree"/>
                    </key-manager>
                </key-managers>
                <server-ssl-contexts>
                    <server-ssl-context name="applicationSSC" key-manager="applicationKM"/>
                </server-ssl-contexts>
            </tls>
```

We've removed `generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhsot"` from configuration because certificate is not self-signed in our case.
Like I mentioned before, same SSL certificate have been used in version 8.1.0.

Please be noted that this is specifically related to version 26.0.1.Final and I have no idea if any more configuration is required apart from the above.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I do have the same problem, we are migrating from wildfly 10 to 26, 
as we have updated from java 8 to java 17
Does anybody know how to configure this?

Comment: @Mintakastar In my case it is standalone mode. After configuring SSL this was the only thing I was missing. Try starting wildfly with below command which binds jboss to all interface.
`./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Dorg.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager="org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I sorted out with the help of Wildfly support. In my case it's standalone mode.

TLS Block:

```
<tls>
                <key-stores>
                    <key-store name="applicationKS">
                        <credential-reference clear-text="password"/>
                        <implementation type="JKS"/>
                        <file path="C:\wildfly26\application.keystore.jks"/>
                    </key-store>
                </key-stores>
                <key-managers>
                    <key-manager name="applicationKM" key-store="applicationKS" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost">
                        <credential-reference clear-text="password"/>
                    </key-manager>
                </key-managers>
                <server-ssl-contexts>
                    <server-ssl-context name="applicationSSC" protocols="TLSv1.2" key-manager="applicationKM"/>
                </server-ssl-contexts>
            </tls>
```

Reference SSL context in https-listener

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="applicationSSC" enable-http2="true"/>
```

Socket Binding under `socket-binding-group`
Change port from 8443 to 443

```
<socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:443}"/>
```

Configure Interface

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
```

Comment: The https listener is now working (following your instructions, thanks) but I get the following error when wildfly is starting:
  WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address..
   failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.filter.server-header"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.filter-ref.server-header is 
missing [jboss.undertow.filter.server-header]"]

  Any ideas why I am getting that and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem since they removed the security realms. I used the top part of this manual: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Simple%20SSL%20Migration.html 
My setup was that I had a .cer certificate and key, I had to re-create the keystore using these two answers: [How to create an empty java trust store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994315/how-to-create-an-empty-java-trust-store) and [How to import an existing X.509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/how-to-import-an-existing-x-509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to)

1. create keystore with dummy certificate: `keytool -genkeypair -alias boguscert -storepass changeit -keypass changeit -keystore server.keystore -dname "CN=Developer, OU=Department, O=Company, L=City, ST=State, C=CA"`
2. delete dummy certificate from keystore: `keytool -delete -alias boguscert -storepass changeit -keystore server.keystore`
3. Create pkcs12 certificate from key and .crt file `openssl pkcs12 -export -in <SERVERNAME>.crt -inkey <SERVERNAME>.key -out server.p12 -name server`
4. import pkcs12 certificate into empty keystore: `keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore server.keystore -srckeystore server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass changeit -alias server`

I then followed the top part of jboss documentation I linked above above using the the wildfly-cli located in the bin directory. 
 This writes the needed xml into the standalone.xml so make sure you use the vanilla one that ships with wildfly 26.0.1. 
 After that I had to enable the ssl redirection using this: [Redirect http requests to https in wildfly 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752067/redirect-http-requests-to-https-in-wildfly-10)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is how my Widfly (20) is configured regarding SSL.

Assuming you have already setup a Java keystore whose entry named 'server' is containing your certificate/key, you have to tell Wildfly to look for that particular alias ('server') in your keystore:

```
<management>
    <security-realms>            
            ...
        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="..." alias="server" key-password="..." generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually the issue is with the Wildfly 26 where they have totally changed the SSL configuration. I don't see this configuration in standalone.xml file as you can see the configuration in my question, even current configuration for SSL does not accept alias in the block.